# jquery form plugin set options

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I am new in this [plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object), as I've read the documentation of this I am having a hard time where to pass the options from here:

```
$('#form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function(options) {
        // status.empty();
        // var percentVal = '0%';
        // bar.width(percentVal)
        // percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        // var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        // bar.width(percentVal)
        // percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        // var percentVal = '100%';
        // bar.width(percentVal)
        // percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        // status.html(xhr.responseText);
        // console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

The output of `console.log(e)` is `{"status":"success","response":"the yes"}`, and if I try `console.log(e.status)` it will return **undefined**. So am I thinking to use, `var options = { dataType: 'json'};` on the option of jQuery form. However, how can I pass the `options` array?

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(e);
console.log(obj.status);
```

use this you have to parse the string e in to json object